# Small Spark dataframe very slow in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I'm using a pretty standard Databricks cluster (2 nodes with 14 GB memory, 4 cores, 0.75 DBU). I have a function `spark_shape` defined as

```
def spark_shape(df):
  """Returns (rows, columns) 
  """
  return (df.count(), len(df.columns))
```

And a simple dataframe `df` that is only of shape (590, 2). However running `spark_shape(df)` takes over 6 minutes! I'm wondering if I need to increase the memory or nodes Databricks cluster except this dataframe is so small I don't understand why a simple operation would take this long. Any ideas?

Comment: What type of files are you reading? And how many files, and average size?

Comment: You can cache the results as well , rather than processing it everytime

Comment: @simon_dmorias The dataframe is just two columns. One is an integer and the other is a double.

Comment: how are you defining df?

Comment: Can you answer the question about the number of files being read and their average size. You almost certainly have a problem with this. Either too many small files, or a single file that is large and causing it to be single threaded.

Comment: @simon_dmorias the original dataset came from one file sized 3.77 MiB.

Comment: Can you post the full code. This should only take a few seconds to run.

Answer (score 1):

Review Spark's query plan to understand how Spark will read and process the data.

```
df.explain()
```

If you have done a lot of preprocessing to `df`, the query plan can get ugly fast. My solution is to save the preprocessed `df` to a new (parquet) file (kind of like a staging table) and then bring that file in as a PySpark Dataframe to do any further operations on the data. This may not be the only or best solution but it's all I've found that works so far.

Answer (score 0):

This function have a very complicated issue.

You can´t know how many time spark evaluation will take to process the dataframe.

Spark architecture does not process things everytime. The Lazy Evaluation only defines what it will need to do to complete the transformations to achieve the desired result. Operations like Join, Merde, Filter, Where are not applied when the code is executed. The operations will only be applied whem some action is used (Count, save, write, display).

Those factors explain why this function is taking so much time. The dataframe is generated inside it, because it has never been fully compiled. You can force this execution saving the df, applying a checkpoint, or using persist (And applying some action, cause persist and cache are also considered transformations that will only be applied when some action is executed).

Those actions will assure the df is compiled and you only exeuted the shape inside this function.